# Change the text in a NSTextField programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsstring, nstextfield

I am used to doing this in Cocoa-touch, so I assumed it would be quite simple. I have already tried:

```
field.text = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%i", number];
[field setText:@"%i", number];
```

and setString, all to no avail.

Comment: You'd be far better off making the API reference your first resource (including superclasses of the one you're investigating). You should especially not ignore compiler errors and run log messages (like the ones you were sure to have received using the code you provided) as they usually tell you exactly what's wrong. This approach will make you a far more effective programmer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will work:

```
[field setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number]];
```

If it doesn't do anything, it probably means `field` isn't set to point to the field (e.g. by making a connection in Interface Builder).

Comment: Thanks, I dont know what I was thinking... Its so obvious!

Comment: In Swift this would be `field.stringValue = ""`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the setStringValue: method that [NSTextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from [NSControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl).

The full signature is:

```
- (void)setStringValue:(NSString *)aString
```